# [Java]Android Videoview works only with local files

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I tried to play a video from a url, but only local videos works in my code. If I try to open a video from a url my nexus 7 displays
Can not play this video. Here is the code for the playback of a local file, it works fine (both are the same videos)

```
package com.sample.prog;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.net.Uri;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static private final String pathToFile = "bigbuck.mp4";
    private VideoView videoPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 

        videoPlayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);   
        videoPlayer.setKeepScreenOn(true);    
        videoPlayer.setVideoPath(root + "/" + pathToFile);
        videoPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

and here is the code for the playback of video from a url, but it don't work

```
package com.sample.prog;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.net.Uri;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static private final String pathToFile = "http://www.myanimesource.de/bigbuck.mp4";
    private VideoView videoPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 

        videoPlayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);   
        videoPlayer.setKeepScreenOn(true);    
        videoPlayer.setVideoPath(URI.parse(pathToFile));
        videoPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

hope you can help me to solve my problem,

regards
christian

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have the correct permissions for internet access; put the following lines in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: According to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30428463/502126), `setVideoURI` vs `setVideoPath` shouldn't matter.