# What is the difference between VideoView's setVideoPath and setVideoURI

Tags: java, android

[VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) has two different ways of specifying which video to play:

- [setVideoPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setVideoPath(java.lang.String))(String path)
- [setVideoUri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setVideoURI(android.net.Uri))(Uri uri)

What is the difference between the two and when should one or the other be used?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at the source code, nothing is different apart from the type you pass.

```
/**
 * Sets video path.
 *
 * @param path the path of the video.
 */
public void setVideoPath(String path) {
    setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
}
/**
 * Sets video URI.
 *
 * @param uri the URI of the video.
 */
public void setVideoURI(Uri uri) {
    setVideoURI(uri, null);
}
```

If you use `setVideoPath` it creates the `Uri` for you, so use whichever you want - depending on if you have a `Uri` or `String` path.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java

Comment: Great! I found very little about it, and it seems like one of the only things I found out turned out to be wrong. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13498435/502126) says that I have to use `setVideoURI` for internet videos.